# Pyinstaller exe doesnt run program

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller

I writed a program with python which using selenium library. Basically, I am opening a page using Chromedriver.exe and login to a site. I want to use this program in another computer without use python.  I want to convert it to a stand-alone exe type.

I tried pyinstaller --onefile filename.py

I got a dist folder which include .exe file. Also I have an .spec file. When I try to run exe file, nothing happen. Just a command panel is opening. How can I run this exe file?

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

    block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['borsaBot_Zpro.py'],
             pathex= 
   ['C:\\Users\\90544\\OneDrive\\Masaüstü\\Yusuf\\ödevler\\borsaBot'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='borsaBot_Zpro',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

[image]

Comment: how does the code look like ?

Comment: Code is too long. I am using selenium, opencv etc. a lot of library.

Comment: Are you getting any errors like Importerror or sth?

Comment: There is no error.

Comment: What is the console window showing?

Comment: Normally, a google page should be opened and some operations should be done on that page. However, nothing happens.

Comment: Try to debug using print statements before and after opening the selenium driver, maybe you can find out where the error is. Maybe Selenium doesnt finde its path could that be?